# calling a function from ng-repeat with the object from the current scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to call a function (from a non event element) from a ng-repeat to feed an array of data to an autocomplete element (using https://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete).

It's to generate a kind of logic system :

```
type(listbox) | comparator (eg:>=) (listbox) | value(autocomplete)
```

And several of those object can be listed on a webpage to get some complex logic

```
type=value && type2>value3 || ...
```

Depending on type and comparator, values are different.

The code so far (simplified):

```
<div class="comparator" ng-repeat="comp in container.comparators">
    <select ng-model="comp.type"><option ng-repeat="i in type_options" value="{{i.value}}" ng-selected="{{i.value==comp.type}}">{{i.label}}</option></select>
    <select ng-model="comp.comparator"><option ng-repeat="i in comp_options|filter:typeMatch(comp)" value="{{i.value}}" ng-selected="{{i.value==comp.comparator}}">{{i.label}}</option></select>
    <autocomplete class="autocomplete" data="" attr-placeholder="Entrez votre valeur" click-activation="true" on-type="**updateValue**" ng-model="comp.value"></autocomplete>
</div>
```

updateValue is the function to call, but i need to know the current object (comp from the ng-repeat) on which i am to send the right array of value.

I tryed to send an existing array to avoid "digest loop"
    $scope.updateValue = function(crit){
        for(var i=0;i

I also tryed to do a function that return a function that return the array :DDDDD :

```
    $scope.updateValue = function(crit){
        return function(value/*not used*/){
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.comp_options.length;i++) {
            if($scope.comp_options[i].value===crit.comparator){
                $scope.value_elements=$scope.comp_options[i].info;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $scope.value_elements;
        };
    };
```

Replacing the autocomplete object with :

if I console.log(comp), I see that I can get my object, but I get a digest loop ...

Is there a way to know the object of the "line" I was called from ?

Thx (i'm a total newbie in angular, but so far, i've been unable to find how to retrieve that information ... is that even possible :) ?).

Answer (score 0):

Access it using $index ? Example below. You can then use the index to access it

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in uc.users track by $index">
            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
            <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            <td>{{user.department}}</td>
            <button ng-click="uc.open(user.id, $index);">Open</button>
</tr>
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but adding the $index in the call force me to use a function that return a function that return the array. And i'd like to avoid that because it makes digest loop.